# Teechart: End labels on logarithmic x-axis

Tags: teechart

If I have a logarithmic x-axis with value from 10 to 400 it displays 10 and 100, but I also want it to display the end value 400.

Another problem is if the values goes from 11 to 400, it only displays label at 100. Here I want to display 11, 100 and 400.

Anyone know what axis/label property to set for this?

Answer (score 0):

To draw such labels you should use custom labels.
I'll assume you are using TeeChart VCL and I'll show code in Delphi, but it would be similar with TeeChart .NET, TeeChart ActiveX or TeeChart Java.

> If I have a logarithmic x-axis with value from 10 to 400 it displays 10 and 100, but I also want it to display the end value 400.

You could do it as follows:

```pascal
uses Series, Math;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=False;
  Chart1.Legend.Hide;
  Chart1.Walls.Hide;
  Chart1.Gradient.Visible:=False;
  Chart1.Color:=clWhite;
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Logarithmic:=True;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TFastLineSeries) as TFastLineSeries do
  begin
    for i:=10 to 400 do
      AddXY(i, sin(i/100));
  end;

  with Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items do
  begin
    Clear;
    Add(10, '10');
    Add(100, '100');
    Add(400, '400');
  end;
end;
```

[image: first]

> Another problem is if the values goes from 11 to 400, it only displays label at 100. Here I want to display 11, 100 and 400.

You could do it as follows:

```pascal
uses Series, Math;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
var i: Integer;
begin
  Chart1.View3D:=False;
  Chart1.Legend.Hide;
  Chart1.Walls.Hide;
  Chart1.Gradient.Visible:=False;
  Chart1.Color:=clWhite;
  Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Logarithmic:=True;

  with Chart1.AddSeries(TFastLineSeries) as TFastLineSeries do
  begin
    for i:=11 to 400 do
      AddXY(i, sin(i/100));
  end;

  with Chart1.Axes.Bottom.Items do
  begin
    Clear;
    Add(11, '11');
    Add(100, '100');
    Add(400, '400');
  end;
end;
```

[image: second]